# Where can I find Environment Hub in Lightning Sales Cloud Enterprise Edition?

Tags: environment-hub

We have Salesforce - Enterprise Edition both Lightning and Classic are available. I'm trying to find "**Environment Hub**" but I can't find it, there's a **Dev Hub** but I think it's different. Anyone here has brilliant ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dev Hub is indeed different than the Environment Hub. The Environment Hub feature is not available by default unless you are an ISV. The first step is to open a Case with Technical Support. You'll want to read [Get Started with the Environment Hub](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/environment_hub_get_started.htm) for more information.

Comment: I am connected to partners.salesforce.com using the same username ... what exactly should I do.

Comment: @victor When you are onboarded, it should automatically be set for you. If not, log a case in the Partner Portal.

Comment: i just get connected to developer.salesforce.com using the enterprise login... and poofff! the Environment Hub is there...  am I in the right place?

Comment: @victor Nope. You need it enabled by support.

Comment: I did contact the support and they said it is already Enabled/Activated.

Comment: @victor Follow the rest of the steps in the docs, then. Use My Domain, etc, etc. There's steps to follow.